# Where does Snow Leopard store per-user StartupItems?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, boot

I have several startup items shown in my "LoginItems" preferences.  But, when I look at my ~/Library folder, there is no StartupItems folder, and the global /Library/StartupItems folder does not contain these things.

So where are they keeping the per-user startup item settings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are being stored in the Preferences.

```
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginitems.plist
```